# Resolving Circular Dependencies in an application with multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, dll, dependency-injection, mef, circular-dependency

In my application which has multiple assemblies.

I have a `Class A` which has a dependency for `dll P`.

To this same class A, I am trying to introduce a new **imported** property which has a dependency for a `dll Q`.

But `dll Q` has a dependency for `dll P`, causing this a circular dependency. `dll P ->dll Q <-dll P`

I have read so many articles but still struggling to find a solution, given that I have to use this **imported** property which has a dependency for a `dll Q`. Any suggestions or advice on the best way to overcome this problem? Is it even possible in the first place?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix the circular dependency problem is to sidestep it completely.

Given that you are using MEF, rather than a IoC/DI framework, I will assume you are doing plugin architecture. If not, don't use MEF, MEF is not IoC/DI.

You want to structure your solution as follows:

```
Common.Interfaces
    interface IQ { }

Plugin.P
    class P { IQ Q { get; set;} }

Plugin.Q
    class Q : IQ {}
```

This way, neither of the projects P or Q directly depends on each other.